# Strange HTML-rendering with Sphinx in python code

Tags: python, python-sphinx, html-rendering

I recently install sphinx doc, 1.2.2, and did a [small tutorial](http://pythonhosted.org/an_example_pypi_project/sphinx.html#function-definitions).

I'm just wondering about the HTML rendering, when i use keyword like
param, parameter, arg, argument, key, keyword, type, etc.. I got an ugly rectangle
which is not in the expected result.

Mine result:
http://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=14/19/i519.png

Tutorial result:
http://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=14/19/0pg8.png

Anyone else got the same issue?
I didn't see somewhere else (in python doc) the same thing.
Thanks

Comment: No image seen. Try to embed it directly into your question - markdown has syntax for it (do not ask me).

Comment: You'll need to upload your images. I don't think SO lets you use external links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial you linked was created with Sphinx 0.6.3. There have been many updates to the code since then. The output you are receiving with your current build is correct for the version of sphinx you are using and the default theme.

If you don't like that output I recommend either changing the [sphinx theme](http://sphinx-doc.org/theming.html) or extending the [template](http://sphinx-doc.org/templating.html) with how you want it to appear.